# LWC Navigation (NavigationMixin) Bug. CurrentPageReference Becomes undefined and won't navigate?

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagereference, navigation, lightningnavigation, navigationmixin.navigate

I'm running into a bizarre bug that I can't track down. When using `NavigationMixin.Navigate` it works just fine MOST of the time. But occasionally, it just stops navigating.

Digging into it as much as I can, it seems like the issue is that `currentPageReference` is suddenly undefined when the issue presents itself. Also I've noticed that when you call `NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl` in this problematic state it returns `JavaScript:Void(0);` instead of the page name, which sort of explains why it isn't going anywhere.

I've tried just setting the `this.currentPageReference` to a valid value, but that seems to have no effect either. Which probably makes sense since you don't have to import `CurrentPageReference` to make the navigation mixin navigate, so it must be checking it elsewhere somehow. Also weird because if I put a `console.log` in the `wire` method for getting the current page reference, it never fires as changed unless it's being updated to a valid value. When it just becomes undefined that method is never called.

Long story short, I'm seeing an issue that after navigating, pages suddenly have an undefined `PageReference`. Is there a way to refresh this? Because I noticed if I just refresh my browser after getting into this state then it DOES get the correct PageReference and carries on as expected. Truly odd.

(Also I should clarify, this is within a Community that this is happening)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wooooow, I finally figured it out. Changing

`{
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        pageName: yourPageName
    }
}`

to

`{
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        pageName: yourPageName,
        actionName: 'view'
    }
}`

fixed it. How? No idea. Did I spend hours on this and am now going to go weep silently in a corner? Yes.

Comment: if page expects recordId, how did you pass that record Id?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the documentation is probably missing the "required" tag on the property attribute, as most PageReference types have a required `actionName`.

[PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type)